# Fastest way to search for multiple values on a linux machine

Tags: linux, grep

I want to search for multiple values (say v1, v2, v3....) in a directory with around 6-10  huge files (~300 MB each). I have tried grep and fgrep, with regular expression search like ('v1 | v2 | v3'). The command seems to be running really slow. I am running something like

```
grep -e 'v1|v2|v3' .
```

Is there a way I can make my search faster? Please note that the machine is single core, so parallelization may not be of much help.

Comment: how are you running it remotely? Try a remote shell...

Comment: Maybe you could be a little more specific about how many files you are searching, what exact commands you tried, how long they took...

Comment: edited the original question. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest

```
LANG=C egrep 'v1|v2|v3'
```

It won't get much faster than that.

Answer (score 0):

You can search with -R option

-R  - Read all files under each directory, recursively.

```
    grep -i 'test' -R .
```